# How do I write a ToJSON/FromJSON instance for a datatype with multiple constructors?

Tags: haskell

Every example I've seen for `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` are for data types with single constructors, like so :

```
data RewindConfig = RConfig JobID Phase
                      deriving Show

instance FromJSON RewindConfig where
  parseJSON (Object o) = RConfig
    <$> o .: "JobID"
    <*> o .: "Phase"
  parseJSON _ = fail "invalid RewindConfig"
```

I thought I would look to how Aeson makes the instance for a type with multiple constructors, for example `Either`:

```
instance (FromJSON a, FromJSON b) => FromJSON (Either a b) where
   parseJSON (Object (H.toList -> [(key, value)]))
        | key == left  = Left  <$> parseJSON value
        | key == right = Right <$> parseJSON value
   parseJSON _        = fail ""
```

The pattern-matching in parseJSON confuses me, I don't understand what is going on with `(H.toList -> [(key, value)])`.

The data type I want to make instances for looks like this:

```
data Foo = Bar String
         | Baz String
         | Bin String
```

it did occur to me to do something I knew how to implement

```
data Foo = (Maybe Bar) (Maybe Baz) (Maybe Bin)
```

But that seems unsatisfying. Could someone help me out by explaining what's going on with the `Either` instance, and perhaps giving me some guidance on To/From instances for `Foo`?

update: I think the instances Aeson implements for `Maybe` are much clearer and tells me what I need to know for my needs. Still, I'd like to know what's going on with `Either`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `(Object (H.toList -> [(key, value)]))` is called a [view pattern](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns). You can read it as something like this:

```
parseJSon (Object o) = case H.toList o of
    [(key, value)]
        | key == left  -> Left  <$> parseJSON value
        | key == right -> Right <$> parseJSON value
```

It's actually slightly different, since the above will always commit to the pattern `Object o` when handed an `Object`, whereas the view pattern will only commit when both the "matches the `Object o` pattern" and the "`H.toList o` matches the `[(key, value)]` pattern" conditions hold, but for this example that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The json package contains an encoding for data types that you might want to adopt.
If you just derive `Data` you can use it.  It's not very fast, but very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each datatype has a distinct key, another approach could use lenses - I like it because it's concise and is readable.  For example if you have a wrapper around an A, B, and C which all have FromJSON instances:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Control.Lens

data Wrap = WrapA A | WrapB B | WrapC C

instance FromJSON Wrap where
    parseJSON json
        | isJust (json ^? key "A's unique key") = WrapA <$> parseJSON json
        | isJust (json ^? key "B's unique key") = WrapB <$> parseJSON json
        | isJust (json ^? key "C's unique key") = WrapC <$> parseJSON json
        | otherwise = fail "Bad message"
```